# Convert basic_string<unsigned char> to basic_string<char> and vice versa

Tags: c++, string, casting, unsigned-char

From the following

[Can I turn unsigned char into char and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078638/can-i-turn-unsigned-char-into-char-and-vice-versa)

it appears that converting a `basic_string<unsigned char>` to a `basic_string<char>` (i.e. `std::string`) is a valid operation. But I can't figure out how to do it.

For example what functions could perform the following conversions, filling in the functionality of these hypothetical `stou` and `utos` functions?

```
typedef basic_string<unsigned char> u_string;
int main() {
    string s = "dog";
    u_string u = stou(s);
    string t = utos(u);
}
```

I've tried to use `reinterpret_cast`, `static_cast`, and a few others but my knowledge of their intended functionality is limited.

Comment: What sort of a conversion do you want?

Comment: @JonathanPotter Anything that would preserve `[A-Za-z0-9]` characters through the conversions from `s` to `t` in the code above.

Comment: `ustring u(s.begin(), s.end());`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you want each character in the original copied across and converted, the solution is simple

```
 u_string u(s.begin(), s.end());
 std:string t(u.begin(), u.end());
```

The formation of `u` is straight forward for any content of `s`, since conversion from `signed char` to `unsigned char` simply uses modulo arithmetic.   So that will work whether `char` is actually `signed` or `unsigned`.

The formation of `t` will have undefined behaviour if `char` is actually `signed char` and any of the individual characters in `u` have values outside the range that a `signed char` can represent.   This is because of overflow of a `signed char`.   For your particular example, undefined behaviour will generally not occur.

Comment: FWIW - complete code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a36d1718cb11f715).  (I was sanity-checking that the `static_cast` in Nicol's answer wasn't needed.)

Answer (score 1):

It is not a legal conversion to *cast* a `basic_string<T>` into any other `basic_string<U>`, even if it's legal to cast `T` to `U`. This is true for pretty much every template type.

If you want to create a new string that is a copy of the original, of a different type, that's easy:

```
basic_string<unsigned char> str(
    static_cast<const unsigned char*>(char_string.c_str()),
    char_string.size());
```