# Why do fstream.read and fstream.write use char and not unsigned char?

Tags: c++, fstream, signedness

As far as I know, `read()` and `write()` are there so we can read and write bytes directly from or to a file, and I was taught that the equivalent of a `byte` in c++ is `unsigned char`, so why do they take `char` pointers as parameters?

Also, do take a look at this function from a "bmp file image reader" library I found:

```
bool BMPImage::readInfo()
{
    //...

    //read bmp and dib headers
    unsigned char header[28] = {0};
    _ifs->read((char*)header, 28);
    _width    = *(int*)&header[18]; //width is located in [18] and is 4 bytes size
    _height   = *(int*)&header[22]; //height is located in [22] and is 4 bytes size
    _bpp      = (unsigned char) *(short*)&header[28]; //bpp is located in [28] and is 2 bytes size
    _channels = _bpp / 8; //set num channels manually

    //...
```

Why does the `_ifs->read()` line work anyway? The cast from unsigned char to char forces loss of data, no?

Comment: "The cast from unsigned char to char forces loss of data, no?"  - no.

Comment: `char` and `unsigned char` have the same size, which is 1 byte. The only difference is signedness: `unsigned char` is always > 0; the normal `char` can also be signed (but doesn't have to be).

Comment: There is no practical difference between `char` and `unsigned char`. But since most people use `char` in their program, it is only natural that API accepts mostly used type.

Comment: [Can I turn unsigned char into char and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15078638/1460794)

Comment: Even better question: why isn't it a void*? That way I can implicitly read data into any pointer without having to do reinterpret_cast.

Answer (score 1):

In C and C++, the standards do not specify whether `char` is signed or unsigned, and implementations are free to implement it as either. There are separate types `signed char` (guaranteed to hold at least the range [-127,127]) and `unsigned char` (guaranteed to hold at least the range [0,255]), and `char` will be equivalent to one of them, but it is implementation defined as to which it is.

Given that the ASCII character set only contains values 0 to 127, it makes sense that, historically, a single signed byte would have been seen as adequate for holding a single character, while still using the same convention as larger types, where integral types are signed by default unless explicitly declared as `unsigned`.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `char` and `unsigned char` have the same size, there should be no data loss when converting between them.

Said that, have in mind that `fstreamm` is just an specialization of `std::basic_fstream` for chars:

```
// from <fstream>
typedef basic_fstream<char>         fstream;
```

You can create your own type for unsigned char, like this:

```
typedef basic_fstream<unsigned char> ufstream;
```

Comment: Are c-style casts fine when doing these file io operations? Also, why do these functions still use char and not unsigned char? or even void* as the c equivalents?

Answer (score 0):

> was taught that the equivalent of a `byte` in c++ is `unsigned char`

I don't know what `byte` is, but you can use `char` to represent a *byte* just fine.

> so why do [fstream.read and fstream.write] take char pointers as parameters?

`fstream` is an alias of `std::basic_fstream<char>`. `std::basic_fstream` is a template whose all operations deal with its specified `char_type`. Since that `char_type` is `char`, all operations deal with `char`, not `unsigned char`.

You could use `basic_fstream<unsigned char>` as Juan suggested, but it's more involved than that. You will need to specialize `char_traits<unsigned char>` which is the second (defaulted) template argument of `basic_fstream<unsigned char>`.

> The cast from unsigned char to char forces loss of data, no?

No. Accessing `unsigned char` through a `char*` loses no data. In fact, accessing any type through `char*` will not lose data.

---

This on the other hand:

```
*(int*)&header[18]
```

has undefined behaviour, unless the buffer was properly aligned such that `header[18]` happens to be located at the boundary required by `int`. I see no such guarantees in the definition of the array. Some architectures do not support unaligned memory access at all.