# Does casting between a char * and unsigned char * have any effect on the data when storing to a file in binary mode

Tags: c

Looking the following approach of initializing a structure, you can see that malloc was not used to allocate a size for `params` in the main, it just pointed to to `array` right away. It prints the values correctly but is this valid practice/ what difference does it make if I allocate a size before the assignment?

```
typedef struct _param_t {
    char * params;
} param_t;

int main()
{
    int i;
    param_t r;
    unsigned char array[5] = {0x01 , 0x02 ,0x03 ,0x04 ,0xFF};
    r.params = (char *) array;
    
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf(" Array %d is %x", i, r.params[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Array 0 is 1 Array 1 is 2 Array 2 is 3 Array 3 is 4 Array 4 is ffffffff
```

On another note, this is the prototype of fwrite used to write to a file:

```
size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
```

It takes in a void pointer. In the main, I cast the array to a `(char *)` to populate the structure. I know that converting between signed T* and unsigned T* in either direction is [generally possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078638/can-i-turn-unsigned-char-into-char-and-vice-versa).

My questions is, what is the difference between writing `r.params` to a file in **binary mode** with `sizeof(unsigned char)` as `size` VS `sizeof(char)` as the `size` parameter ? Both are the same size. Therefore is shouldn't make a difference and reading from the file can then be stored in a char array or an unsigned char array without loss of data, correct?

Comment: In binary mode, `fread` and `fwrite` do not care *what* the data is. They just operate on the size of data at the location you specify. The buffer they take is `const void *buffer` so the functions have no way of knowing anything about the data.

Comment: As a side note, don’t use char(which can be signed or unsigned) when working with bytes always use unsigned char.

Comment: Re “converting between signed T* and unsigned T* in either direction is generally possible”: The answers you link to do not say that. The question is for character types, not a general type T. Character types are special in C and C++.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any differences. The C standard requirements on character types are rather strict: must be 1 byte, must not contain padding bits or trap representations. It is therefore very likely that `char` and `unsigned char` have the same binary representation, regardless of if `char` is signed or unsigned on the given system. It is also perfectly safe to convert between the different character types.

Generally, when you want to use raw binary representations, use `uint8_t` instead, never `char`.

As you noted, `printf` family of functions will promote small integer types to `int` though. So in case `char` is signed, an impl.defined conversion to 2's complement negative number will happen in the 0xFF case. Upon promotion to 32 bit `int`, this is "sign extended into" 0xFFFFFFFF, which is then printed as an unsigned number using the `%x` specifier, that expects type `unsigned int`.

Answer (score -2):

### No

Answer to your question is no.

### Data is always stored as binary

`Data types` in programming languages only exists for the ease of writing code

For example:

```
char character = `c`;    // binary stored in character is 0110 0011

unsigned char variable = character // will store 0110 0011 in variable
```

And `pointers` are just used to access the memory location of variables.

So when you Point to a `char` using a `unsigned char*`, only the way that data is interpreted is changed but the **binary behind it is the same**

Comment: This is incorrect. When the standard allows implicit typecasting may change the underlying representation of the data as well. `int a=42; double b=a`. `b` will not be `0x2A`, but rather the IEEE 754 representation of the number closest to `42`

Comment: I was talking about `pointing to data`, not `casting` and storing it in another `variable`. Data stored in a memory location will be the same irrespective of the `data type` used to point to it. In my examples I have used `char` and `unsigned char`, and not `int` and `double`.