# Convert sqlite3 result columns to string

Tags: c++, string, sqlite, char

I am using SQLITE3 and can successfully read data from a SQLITE database
table and display it in C++ like so:

```cpp
cout << sqlite3_column_text(dbResult, 1);
```

However, I need to convert the column result into a string.
Is there perhaps an easy way in C++ to convert char into string?
Have been trying to find a solution, but to no avail.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: At least (and without knowledge of the sqlite3 API), if you can output it into a stream, you can output into a `std::ostringstream`. Afterwards, you can return the `std::string` with `std::ostringstream::str()`. (Though, if it's really just a `char` then you could assign or add the `char` to a `std::string` directly.)

Comment: Thank you Scheff's Cat
Was really hoping there was a more elegant way like in MQL4, where I could just use: "string myResult = CharToStr(sqlite3_column_text(dbResult, 1));" to achieve this.

Comment: Are we really talking about a `char` or a `const char*`? What stops you to write `std::string myResult = sqlite3_column_text(dbResult, 1);`? (Did you even try this?)

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying, but it throws the following error: ....cpp:3625: error: no viable conversion from 
'const unsigned char *' to 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>')

Answer (score 0):

According to doc. [**sqlite3_column_text()**](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html) is declared as:

> `const unsigned char *sqlite3_column_text(sqlite3_stmt*, int iCol);`

For any reason, it returns a `const unsigned char*`. (This might be for historical reasons to emphasize the fact that the returned string is UTF-8 encoded.)

Thus, for assignment to a `std::string` (which can be assigned with `const char*` expressions among others), a small dirty trick does the job:

```
std::string myResult = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(dbResult, 1);
```

This reclaims the sequence of `unsigned char`s to be a sequence of `char`s.

Please, note that the signedness of `char` is left to the compiler implementation and may be signed or unsigned. (In the major compilers MSVC, g++, clang, it's in fact signed.) Hence, it's accompanied by types `signed char` and `unsigned char` to make the signedness explicit (and independent of the used compiler) when necessary. The conversion in the above snippet doesn't change any contents of the returned string — it just makes it compatible for the assignment to `std::string`.

---

Googling a bit, I found another Q/A where the answer explains that the "small dirty trick" is legal according to the C++ standard:

[**Can I turn unsigned char into char and vice versa?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15172304/7478597)